# sed with ANSI color escapes fail

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sed

I do not know why this does not work:

```
echo -e "$(echo "This is an uncolored text" | sed "s/{This is an uncolored text}/{This is an \033[0;34uncolored text\033[0m}/g")"
```

but this works well:

```
echo "$(echo "Hello World" | sed "s/Hello/Hi/g")"
```

May you explain to me?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what exactly you mean with "this does not work". What actual output do you get? What do you want to get?

Comment: The following command: start_command echo "this is an uncolored text" | sed 's/This is an uncolored text/This is an \\033\[0;34muncolored text\\033\[0m/g' end_commend still does not work

Comment: Could you paste the final result. I do not get it only by substituting ```[``` by ```\[```

Comment: The original problem takes an uncolored string and substitutes it by it colored one. However, as you can see, the colored version lacks some backslashes.

Comment: Problem solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of issues.

First, the braces `{...}` in your sed expression are not matched by anything in the input. In a sed Basic Regular Expression, braces are literal, while in an Extended Regular Expression they surround a quantifier of the form `{n,m}`. They are never used for grouping.

Second, your color sequence is malformed - the opening needs to be `\033[0;34m` rather than `\033[0;34`

Third, the backslash character `\` is special in sed - in particular, a backslash followed by a decimal digit on the RHS of a substitution is a backreference to a capture group; at least in GNU sed, `\0` refers to the whole captured LHS equivalent to the special replacement token `&` so for example

```
$ echo foo | sed 's/foo/\033bar/'
foo33bar
```

To pass a literal `\` to the outer `echo -e` you'd need `\\` inside the sed replacement string.

Finally, `\` is *also* special to the shell, so inside "soft" double quotes needs an additional backslash. So either:

```
echo -e "$(echo "This is an uncolored text" | 
  sed "s/This is an uncolored text/This is an \\\033[0;34muncolored text\\\033[0m/")"
```

or (replacing the inner double quotes with 'strong' single quotes):

```
echo -e "$(echo "This is an uncolored text" | 
  sed 's/This is an uncolored text/This is an \\033[0;34muncolored text\\033[0m/')"
```

Note that you don't need the `g` modifier to make a single replacement per line.

See also [What characters do I need to escape when using sed in a sh script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32907/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-when-using-sed-in-a-sh-script)

Comment: I worked my way out. Take a look at the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

My worked out solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

colored_text='this is a \\033[0;34mtext\\033[0m'
uncolored_text='this is a text'

printf %b\\n "$(sed "s/$uncolored_text/$colored_text/" <<< "$uncolored_text")"
```

Comment: Thanks, bac0n! It smells good.